# jQuery dropdown menus

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery dropdown menu with the following HTML:

```
<dl class="dropdown">
               <dt><a id="linkglobal1"><span class="icon lock">Action</span></a></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul id="ulglobal1">
                        <li><a href="#"><span>Everyone</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>Friends</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>Only Me</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>Customize</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </dd>
            </dl>
```

and then the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('dl.dropdown dt a').click(function()
    {
        $("dl.dropdown dt a").removeClass("selected");
        var toggleId = "#" + this.id.replace(/^link/,"ul");
        $('dl.dropdown dd ul').not(toggleId).hide();
        $(toggleId).toggle();
        if($(toggleId).css("display") == "none")
        {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
    });
    $("dl.dropdown dd ul li a").click(function()
    {
        $("dl.dropdown dd ul").hide();
        $("dl.dropdown dt a").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(document).bind('click', function(e)
    {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
        {
            $("dl.dropdown dd ul").hide();
            $("dl.dropdown dt a").removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I am having is that it relies on using ID's on both the `<dt>` link and the `<ul>`. How can I modify my jQuery so that it no longer relies on them?

Thanks

**EDIT: I've answered this myself. See below.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it with this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('dl.dropdown dt a').click(function()
    {
        $("dl.dropdown dt a").removeClass("selected");

        var toggleMenu = $(this).parent().parent().find('dd ul');

        $(toggleMenu).toggle();

        $('dl.dropdown dd ul').not(toggleMenu).hide();

        if(toggleMenu.css("display") == "none")
        {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
    });
    $("dl.dropdown dd ul li a").click(function()
    {
        $("dl.dropdown dd ul").hide();
        $("dl.dropdown dt a").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(document).bind('click', function(e)
    {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
        {
            $("dl.dropdown dd ul").hide();
            $("dl.dropdown dt a").removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give those items classes.  the classes don't need  to exist.

```
                <ul id="ulglobal1" class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Everyone</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Friends</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Only Me</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Customize</span></a></li>
              </ul>
```

then your jquery selector uses

```
$(".dropdown")....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jbar jQuery plugin
jbar is a jQuery plugin that transforms an unordered list  into a toolbar with dropdown menus. Please follow the following link:-
[jbar@GitHub](https://github.com/javan/jbar)

Comment: Hi I don't want to use a plugin as I have already built my menu I just want to modify the code to no longer require id's.